# How can I make an EC2 instance report a custom hostname

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, web-server, varnish

I purchased an amazon ec2 instance, where I configured a webserver.
Then I purchased Route53 to handle dns, where I set my custom domain to point on the Elastic IP.

The fact is that when typing my domain name the server web answers using the AmazonAws.com domain!!

I'm running varnish in front of apache2.

How can I fix that?

Comment: What do you mean "the web server answers using the AmazonAws.com domain"? Please edit your question and tell us **exactly** what actions you're performing and what results you're seeing.

Comment: Also, please edit the title. I'd edit it to be something like "How can I make an EC2 instance report a custom hostname?" but I'm not certain that's what you were asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question I'm guessing one of two things is happening:

1. You're seeing Apache's default server banner with the hostname included. You need to update the system's hostname or specify something in the httpd.conf. This is not specific to AWS.
2. If not 1, then you're probably referring to the reverse-DNS of your server's IP resolving to an AWS hostname. If you need valid reverse-DNS with your custom domain you'll need an Elastic IP as noted here: 
   http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Can_I_configure_the_reverse_DNS_record_for_my_Elastic_IP_address

In any case we need to know what you mean by "the server web answers using the AmazonAws.com domain" in order to answer your question.

Comment: Yeah it was an apache configuration issue.